# Could it be possible to answer a new research question with the help of literature review? Could this be published at a symposium?

Tags: conference, independent-researcher, publishability, economics

I am a master student and my university didn't teach us econometrics, but I am doing self study. So, right now I am not adept at and could handle large time series data. But I sent an abstract to a conference, and they have accepted it.

I am unable to handle large data and technicalities of macroeconomy. But since I am doing this all by myself, I am finding it difficult to apply techniques. My research question is unique, and no one has answered it, so is it possible if I do but with the help of past literature?

Answer (score 2):

Actually, for most things you need a literature review, since you need to know what has been done already. But if the complete answer shows up in the review then there is nothing left to research there and you need to move on.

I hope you have an advisor somewhere, or access to some sort of academic guide. You seem to be unsure about how to handle things, and a guide can help get you on the right track.

And doing a good literature review can also help teach you common techniques that you will need to answer your question.